# Should I texturize my ceiling after removing popcorn?

Tags: ceiling, texture

I'm going to remove the popcorn ceiling in my 90's era house and was wondering if I should texturize after removing it.  The walls have the "orange peel" type of texture on them but I just don't know if it would be best to have everything match or if a primered/painted ceiling would be OK with texturized walls.

Comment: This is very subjective.  Get a can of spray texture, try a part of the ceiling and decide if you like the look.  If you don't like it, the texture will wipe off easily while it's wet.

Comment: Why bother removing the popcorn if you're going to put texture back up?

Comment: Oh please, NO. When you sell your house the new owners will curse you.

Comment: This is an aesthetic question and has no real definitive answer. Such questions are not well suited to this format.  [faq]

Answer (score 1):

I would leave it flat. That's the whole idea of scraping off popcorn. In almost ever home remodel show, they want to remove the popcorn.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question exactly, but it's an alternative you might consider.

If you want to go with a completely flat ceiling but don't want to remove the current ceiling, you can simply put new drywall attached through the existing ceiling.  My in-laws recently did this in their living room and it looks great (you wouldn't know that's what they did if someone didn't tell you).  The contractor liked the idea of not having to take down the existing and dealing with all the blown insulation.